# Username entries all come out as 'null' in mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm getting started in node.js and trying to create a user authentication system for my web application. I am watching a tutorial on YouTube and have followed every step through. When it comes to actually registering my user. the username entry in the collecting comes out as null. I'm not sure why this is happening, and I'm a rookie to javascript and node js. I am using passport, express and mongodb modules.

this is the video i am watching 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2ZzRZemc98'
If anyone knows how to fix my issue, please respond

## Thanks

This is my main app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const passport = require("passport");
const Strategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const authUtils = require("./utils/auth");
const hbs = require("hbs");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");

var app = express();

//Connet to MongoDB database
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost", (err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  const db = client.db("user-profiles");
  const users = db.collection("users");
  app.locals.users = users;
});

//Passport streategy
passport.use(
  new Strategy((username, passport, done) => {
    app.locals.users.findOne({ username }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      if (user.password != authUtils.hashPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  })
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  done(null, { id });
});

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");
hbs.registerPartials(path.join(__dirname, "views/partials"));

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "session secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.loggedIn = req.isAuthenticated();
  next();
});
app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my auth.js

```
const router = express.Router();
const authUtils = require("../utils/auth");
const passport = require("passport");

router.get("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  const messages = req.flash();
  res.render("login", { messages });
});

router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/auth/login",
    failureFlash: "Wrong username or password"
  }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect("/users");
  }
);

router.get("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  const messages = req.flash();
  res.render("register", { messages });
});

router.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  const registrationParams = req.body;
  const users = req.app.locals.users;
  const payload = {
    username: registrationParams.username,
    password: authUtils.hashPassword(registrationParams.password)
  };

  users.insertOne(payload, err => {
    if (err) {
      req.flash("error", "User account already exists");
    } else {
      req.flash("success", "User account was registered succesfully");
    }

    res.redirect("/auth/register");
  });
});

router.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: please add relevant code in the question

Comment: Please explain your problem

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error, it was a mistake i made in the handlebars file, i put the input name as none the class of form-control and then named it again. Obviously the js looked at the first name and not the second name

Comment: You can actually delete your question, As there is no actual issue apart from user's typo !!